# Setting up Socket io in an Express server (Error: TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an Express server which works well, but now I want to set up Socket.io in it,
I have the error `TypeError: require(...).listen is not a function`

My current code (working well)

```
const app = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("Server running");
});
```

Code trying to set up Socket.io

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server running");
});
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
```

Can someone help me with the error above please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SocketIO documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat), to setup SocketIO with the express application, it should be:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Comment: oh so I have to use the http package ?

Comment: yes, and `http` is a built in package in Nodejs; you don't need to install it